# Detect mouse and keyboard connected

Tags: keyboard, bash, mouse, login

I use a Raspberry Pi as TV. I want to login to PIXEL if keyboard or mouse are connected and login to Kodi if keyboard or mouse are not connected and the Raspberry is connected to TV. I want to login to Pixel if connected remotely.
How can I config raspberry?

I find that I can write a Bash script in `~/xsession` to specify what session to be loaded but how can I detect status of keyboard, mouse or TV connection?

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/399698/execute-a-command-when-a-device-is-connected-via-usb).